# Java - Convert JSON data to java objects without knowing explicitly the type

Tags: java, json

Supposedly that I need to retrieve data from an external API (Not designed by me) that returns data in JSON format, as following (Only for illustrating my question, not the actual output format/info)

```
{
  "variables":[{"a":15, "b":true, "c":10.05, "d":"2022-10-15"},
               {"a":16, "b":false, "c":11.25, "d":"2022-01-01"}]
}
```

For the result returned by this API, it is known that the data type can only be `String`,`Boolean`,`Date` or `Double`. However, the type is not explicitly given in the JSON. As far as converting JSON to Java objects, I can convert them all to `Object`.

However, to allow further manipulation under the appropriate class, is there a better way to convert those objects to the appropriate types?

I have thought about using `try/catch` to try to convert the `Object` to these 4 types. However, I imagine this won't be the ideal way. So I am wondering what other ways can be better for this situation.

PS: I understand that the best solution would to ask whoever designed the API to include the data type. But I would like to see if it can work without having explicit information on the data type of each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jackson's `ObjectMapper`, you can parse the JSON data as a `JsonNode`. After your access the values, you can inspect the class name of each `ValueNode`.

**Note:** The values `True` and `False` are not valid in JSON. They must be lowercase variants `true` and `false` respectively. I called `toLowerCase()` on the JSON string as a lazy way to make it parseable.

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ValueNode;

public class JsonParser {
    private static final String JSON_DATA = "{\"variables\":[{\"a\":15,\"b\":True,\"c\":10.05,\"d\":\"2022-10-15\"},{\"a\":16,\"b\":False,\"c\":11.25,\"d\":\"2022-01-01\"}]}";

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String getTypeOfNode(ValueNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            switch (node.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                case "IntNode":
                    return "int";
                case "BooleanNode":
                    return "boolean";
                case "DoubleNode":
                    return "double";
                case "TextNode":
                    return "String"; // timestamp
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(JSON_DATA.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
        JsonNode variables = root.get("variables"); // variables.isArray() == true

        for (JsonNode variable : variables) {
            System.out.printf("Type of a: %s%n", getTypeOfNode((ValueNode) variable.get("a")));
            System.out.printf("Type of b: %s%n", getTypeOfNode((ValueNode) variable.get("b")));
            System.out.printf("Type of c: %s%n", getTypeOfNode((ValueNode) variable.get("c")));
            System.out.printf("Type of d: %s%n", getTypeOfNode((ValueNode) variable.get("d")));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this information to unwrap the underlying value from the `ValueNode` and set it on your own model data object.

Output:

```
Type of a: int
Type of b: boolean
Type of c: double
Type of d: String
Type of a: int
Type of b: boolean
Type of c: double
Type of d: String
```

---

### A better way

Using a custom Jackson deserializer module and Lombok, we can shorten this code and get true type inference during deserialization.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import lombok.Data;

public class JsonParserAdvanced {
    private static final String JSON_DATA = "{\"variables\":[{\"a\":15,\"b\":True,\"c\":10.05,\"d\":\"2022-10-15\"},{\"a\":16,\"b\":False,\"c\":11.25,\"d\":\"2022-01-01\"}]}";

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    static {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new CustomLocalDateDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        Payload payload = objectMapper.readValue(JSON_DATA.toLowerCase(Locale.US), Payload.class);
        for (Variable variable : payload.getVariables()) {
            System.out.println(variable);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomLocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {
        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;

        public CustomLocalDateDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public CustomLocalDateDeserializer(Class<?> valueClass) {
            super(valueClass);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
            return LocalDate.parse(jsonParser.getText(), formatter);
        }
    }

    @Data
    private static class Variable {
        private int a;
        private boolean b;
        private double c;
        private LocalDate d;
    }

    @Data
    private static class Payload {
        private Variable[] variables;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JsonParserAdvanced.Variable(a=15, b=true, c=10.05, d=2022-10-15)
JsonParserAdvanced.Variable(a=16, b=false, c=11.25, d=2022-01-01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple if can work:

```
if(variable instanceof Integer){}
else if(variable instanceof String){}
(...)
```